# Swift UnsafeMutableRawPointer returns class instead of instance

Tags: swift, pointers, macos-carbon

I’d expect this code to return an `NSString` with the ID of the currently selected input source. Instead, it seems to return one of the `NSString` classes itself.

```
import Foundation
import Carbon

let current = TISCopyCurrentKeyboardInputSource().takeUnretainedValue()

let id = TISGetInputSourceProperty(current, kTISPropertyInputSourceID).load(as: NSString.self)
id.length
```

When I run this in my macOS app, I get this error message in the logs: `+[__NSCFConstantString _fastCStringContents:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x7fff92cf79e8`. How can I fix this issue so I get the correct returned value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TISGetInputSourceProperty()` returns an (unmanaged) raw pointer which must be *converted* to a `CFStringRef`, not *dereferenced* with `load()`. The `CFString` can then be bridged to a Swift `String`.

```
let current = TISCopyCurrentKeyboardInputSource().takeRetainedValue()
if let ptr = TISGetInputSourceProperty(current, kTISPropertyInputSourceID) {
    let id = Unmanaged<CFString>.fromOpaque(ptr).takeUnretainedValue() as String
    print(id) // com.apple.keylayout.German
}
```

Note also that `takeRetainedValue()` must be used on the return value of `TISCopyCurrentKeyboardInputSource()` because that function returns a (+1) retained reference, otherwise you'll have a memory leak.